# jQuery navigate DOM to closest tr in table

Tags: jquery, dom

I need to select row **tr** property(class) and change it. I am lost when I want to select this **tr** top from cell:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr class="a">
        <td>name</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text22222</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="inpu" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="a">
        <td>name</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text2</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="inpu" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.inpu').click(function()
{
     alert( $(this).parent().parent().closest('tr')[0].html() );                         
});
```

[Link to jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/bfjp8ov8/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are over-complicating thing use `closest()` directly

```
var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
```

You current problem is `$(this).parent().parent()` is referring to `tr` and it doesn't have `tr` as parent element, thus your code is not working.

```
$(this) //Element
.parent() //TD
.parent() //TR
```

Comment: yes, works:
$(this).closest('tr').prop("class","bbb" );

Comment: @Jerry1 `$(this).closest('tr').addClass('bbb');` if you want add class use the function

Answer (score 1):

Just Use **Closest()** Function ..

```js
$('.inpu').click(function(){

alert( $(this).closest('tr').prop('class') );
      
$(this).closest('tr').addClass('abc')  ;          
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="a">
        <td>name</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text22222</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="inpu" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="a">
        <td>name</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text2</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="inpu" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closest()` directly on the `this` reference to get the nearest parent element of a specific type, then call `addClass` to amend the `class` property:

```
$('.inpu').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('foo');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.inpuy').click(function(){
        alert( $(this).closest('tr').html() );
});
```